# Sarah's quotation functions

Tags: python-3.x

I am struggling with this code. It says I need different quotations so I changed them but then it switches again saying I needed the ones I had before. I keep switching it back to forth but its not working. Here is my code

## Take a message and return a version with quotation marks around it

```
def add_quotes(message):
  return '"' + message + '"'

message = input('Enter a message: ')

print("You said '" + message + "'")
```

Comment: What do you mean, *"It says I need different quotations"*? What is "it", and what *exactly* does it say?

Comment: What do you intend to do? Could you provide with an example that includes input and expected output for the given input?

Comment: What I mean is it will tell me to do these quotations " ..." but then I submit it and it says I should've done these quotations '...' and it keeps doing that back and forth

Answer (score 1):

## try using formatting.

## and remember to call the method add_quote

```py
def add_quotes(message):
        
     return '"{}"'.format(message)
    
message = input('Enter a message: ')
message = add_quotes(message)

print('You said ' + message)
```